# req.body check if it contains a specific character

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On my register page, I use body-parser to process req.body.username. How can I make it check for a specific character and if it is found, deny the registration form? Basically disallowing users to create a username containing the character: **?**

Passport.js:

```
   passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    gameusernameField: 'username',
    nicknameField: 'nickname',
    passReqToCallback: true
},

function(req, username, password, done) {

    // here you read from req
    const email = req.body.email;
    const nickname = req.body.nickname;
            newUserMysql.email = email;
            newUserMysql.password = password;
            newUserMysql.username = username;
            newUserMysql.nickname = nickname;
```

Server.js:

```
//For BodyParser
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(flash());

// For Passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
})); // session secret
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
```

Comment: if that's your actual secret, remember to delete it after.

Comment: It is not @Trufa

Comment: `if (req.body.username.indexOf("?" )> -1`?

Comment: @tymeJV Could you provide more details? Where do I place this code and how does it Work?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, do you not know how to check for specific chars? or in this particular case?

Comment: @Trufa I never worked with passport.js and body-parser before.

Comment: @JavaSherwood - `String.indexOf(char)` will return the index of the specified character... if it's `-1`, that means the character doesnt exist in the specified string.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (req.body.username.indexOf('?') > -1) {
    //reject
} else {
    //accept and continue
}
```

Comment: Sweet! Thank you.

Comment: @JavaSherwood In ES6 you can also use `req.body.username.includes('?')`